# struct pointer member and memory management

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm wondering what happens to a struct member that is pointing to a non-dynamically allocated variable. So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
    int *pointer;
} MyStruct;

int year = 1989;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    MyStruct *myStruct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));

    myStruct->value = 100;
    myStruct->pointer = &year;

    year++;

    printf("%d \n", *myStruct->pointer);

    // what happens to the myStruct->pointer member when we free myStruct ?
    free(myStruct);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I assume it's destroyed an no longer points to **year** correct? If that is the case, the same would be true if *pointer where pointing to a function right?

like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    void (*someFunc)();
} MyStruct;
```

Then later:

```
void sayHi(){
  printf("hi");
}

...

myStruct->someFunc = sayHi;
```

No special cleanup needed except free() if our struct was created with malloc? Thanks for any insights anyone has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you didn't `malloc` (or `calloc/strdup/realloc`) it you don't need to free it. Nothing special is needed - the member variable just points at something, it doesn't logically "own" the pointed at memory.

Your `year` member variable will still exist and is perfectly valid after you `free(myStruct)` - `myStruct->pointer` will be invalid to use though

Comment: cool. That's what I thought. (need more rep to upvote, but I will when I have it).

Comment: @Ralph D: No worries. Wait a while, see which answer is best in terms of clearly explaining this, and then accept that answer - that'll help the next guy finding this question.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. I'm really enjoying learning C.